# How to change Eclipse's file search input bar font

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes, editor

In Eclipse, if u ctrl-h, you'll get a window popup to help you search for files. The input bar for me in this window, and only in this window, has a white background and white text. Not other windows, say the open/new file window. The only way for me to see the letter is if i were to highlight it and turn the background navy-blue

Comment: The light or the dark theme? Which operating system? The dark theme has been improved in the latest releases. So make  sure you are using Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11).

Comment: Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). Dark theme. I downloaded and am using Sublime Monokai theme